# why am I not able to call the Jquery function inside the if expression

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

//CheckMyWeight is called Perfectly here and not in the if loop expression

if ($("#frm1").validationEngine({returnIsValid:true}) && CheckMyWeight() && a === b) {  

}});
```

why i am not able to call the "CheckMyWeight()" in the if loop expression and i am able to call perfectly 
after the "#btn1" function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the left side of the `&&` returns falsy, the right side won't be evaluated.  (since the whole expression cannot possibly be true)
This is called short-circuiting.

If you want to always call both functions, you should call them outside the condition and assign the results to variables, **and leave a comment explaining why**:

```
var isValid = $("#frm1").validationEngine({returnIsValid:true});
var isHeavy = CheckMyWeight();   //Always call both functions
if (isValid && isHeavy && a === b) {  
    ...
}
```

There are other workarounds, but they hide the intention of the code.

Comment: @SLaks:How can i Call That Function too

Comment: it is left to right, that's why a statement like `if( object && object.property )` works.

Comment: `falsy` = `false`  and `ant` = `want` :)

Comment: @Gaby: No, it doesn't.  `"" && alert("Wrong!")` won't show anything.

Comment: @SLaks, i just meant you have a typo .. (*bad usage of code tag on my part..*)

Comment: @Gaby `falsy == false` but `falsy !== false`!

Comment: The second one is a typo; the first one isn't.  I specifically meant `falsy`.

Comment: @SLaks: +1 for Informing a new topic

Answer (score 0):

The below is a small program to test whether u can call the "CheckMyWeight()" in the if loop expression .Its working so the problem is with $("#frm1").validationEngine({returnIsValid:true} try to work by breaking the conditions.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('body');
        function CheckMyWeight() {
          return true;
        }
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var a =1,b=1;
            //CheckMyWeight is called Perfectly here and not in the if loop expression
    //        CheckMyWeight() &&
            if ( CheckMyWeight() && a === b) {
                alert('hi');
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn1">Click me</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```